# RefineryCMS - undefined method `escape_path' for Rack::Utils:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm using `refinerycms` `v 1.0.9` in my project.

When I opening pages which contain images I get an error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/images#index

Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@fairy/gems/refinerycms-images-1.0.9/app/views/admin/images/_grid_view.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `escape_path' for Rack::Utils:Module
```

As I understood method `escape_path` included in Rack versions newer than mine. My refinery version is using Rack `1.2.8` and I can't update Rack version because in this case Refinery fails.

I believe I've missed something important. How can I solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any solution and I tried to expand old `Rack::Utils` module with missing method.

```
require 'rack/utils'

module Rack
  module Utils
    def escape_path(s)
      escape(s).gsub('+', '%20')
    end
    module_function :escape_path
  end
end
```

I added it to `config/initializers`